# How does plt.savefig handle file handler issues(file reference open/close) internally?

Tags: python, matplotlib, file-handling

I am writing code to create plots and save them using plt.savefig method in matplotlib.

I want to know how this function deals with file handling issues (closing file handles to be precise) and to be sure if this doesn't cause memory management issues when I am creating a lot of such plots.

I tried looking up the code base of MatPlotLib and a few StackOverflow questions regarding this and haven't found anything yet.

My guess is, since I am not creating a file handler there doesn't exist any reference to be closed. Yet, I want to be sure with this hypothesis and would want to understand what exactly happens in the backend.

```
    data_array = np.random.normal(size=10)
    plt.boxplot(data_array)
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(path_to_file,"box_plot.png"))
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends which backend you use to draw your images actually. From the snippet you posted, matplotlib will guess that is should use the PNG backend.
Which in turn creates an instance of `matplotlib.backends.backend_agg.FigureCanvasAgg`.

This class does the actual saving like this:

```
def print_raw(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    renderer = self.get_renderer()
    with cbook._setattr_cm(renderer, dpi=self.figure.dpi), \
            cbook.open_file_cm(filename_or_obj, "wb") as fh:
        fh.write(renderer._renderer.buffer_rgba())
```

So there are no dangling open files. The file is guaranteed to be closed properly.
Take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/d4f1f8d0b1b71c97c3f750dfa9c16c1e9ab3261b/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py#L479).

Comment: Matplotlib will use `print_png` not `print_raw` to save a png. Of course the argument stays the same. Though the link to the source seems strange, maybe that is an old version? Because nowadays, matplotlib will first try to save via `PIL`/`Pillow`, `PIL.Image.save()` in case pillow is found in the system. It'll then depend on whether PIL handles saving well. But sure.. there is in general no reason to assume that this would not be the case.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! @Oz123. This made things clear.